# Comparing non-optional value of type 'Bool' to 'nil' always returns true

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement

I have an if-else statement where I am checking if the value coming from user defaults is nil or not like this:

```
 if defaults.bool(forKey: "abcd") != nil{
       //Do something
    }
    else{
        //do something else
    }
```

But Xcode is giving me an error saying:
"Comparing non-optional value of type 'Bool' to 'nil' always returns true"

Can someone explain what's happening here and how to fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid compiler-designers fall into the ["curse of knowledge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge) (once you understand something, it's really hard to think accurately like someone who doesn't yet know it), so some error messages that are obvious to people in-the-know, might be non-obvious to others. So I'm curious, what's your understanding of this error message, as you read it?

Comment: Hey @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, from what I understand, the value returned is either true or false and hence never nil, even if the key-value does not exist. But what I want to know is a better way to implement this kind of logic where I want to check if the key does not exist then do something and if it does then do something else. Right now the code still seems to be working but what's troubling me is that I don't fully understand or rather understood the logic behind.

Comment: "hence never nil, even if the key-value does not exist." Precisely, so a comparison to `nil` here (in addition being invalid, type wise) isnn't what you're looking for. If you look at the [documentation for `bool(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416388-bool), you'll see: "The Boolean value associated with the specified key. If the specified key doesn‘t exist, this method returns false." Thus, when you get `false` back, you have no way of differentiating between "nothing was there" and "something was there, and it was actually `false`".

Comment: You can either structure your boolean so that `false` is a good default for indicating missing values (which may require flipping the meaning of the boolean, e.g. changing `isHidden` to `isVisible`, so that the meaning of `true` and `false` are swapped), or you need to use another approach, such as using `object(forKey:)`, which uses `nil` to indicate "missing". You can then try to cast with `as? Bool`, where a `nil` result will mean you had a value for the key, but it wasn't a bool. Finally, if you end up with a `Bool`, you know that it was a `true`/`false` value that was actually there

Comment: That sounds like a good idea to make it work @Alexander-ReinstateMonica 
Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

`bool(forKey:)` returns a NON-optional, which cannot be nil. If the key is missing in the user defaults, the return value will be `false`.

If you want trinary logic here (nil/true/false) use `object(forKey:)` looking for an NSNumber, and if present, take its `boolValue`.

Answer (score 1):

As

```
defaults.bool(forKey: "abcd")
```

will return `false` by default check [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416388-bool) , so it will never be optional

> The Boolean value associated with the specified key. If the specified key doesn‘t exist, this method returns false.

Answer (score 0):

The func bool(forKey: "abcd") returns Bool type not optional.

Which means you cant compare it to bool, what you can do is simply:

```
 if defaults.bool(forKey: "abcd") {
   //Do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Now if the key exists and has true value it will get into the if statement, if it does not exists or is false it will go to the else.

If you have any doubts you can read about the func in the following Apple developer link: [Apple:bool(forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416388-bool)

Answer (score 0):

Objective-c property in swift. If you're using some objective c property in swift and it says something like **"Comparing non-optional value of type 'XYZ' to 'nil' always returns true"** you have to make that objective c property to **"_Nullable"** so that property may not be optional anymore. Like `@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *_Nullable someString;`

Answer (score 0):

> `defaults.bool(forKey: "abcd") != nil`

The first part, `defaults.bool(forKey: "abcd")`, returns a non-optional boolean. We know that because [`bool(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1410095-object) returns `Bool`, not `Bool?`. Therefore, you'll always get a `Bool` value, i.e. either `true` or `false`, never `nil`. Note the documentation:

*If the specified key doesn‘t exist, this method returns false.*

> "Comparing non-optional value of type 'Bool' to 'nil' always returns true"

The compiler is simply pointing out that it *knows* that `defaults.bool(forKey: "abcd")` can't be `nil`, and since you're comparing it to `nil`, you're probably making a mistake. Your `else` block will never execute.

> Can someone explain what's happening here and how to fix this?

It depends on what you mean for the code to do. If you want to take different actions depending on whether the value is `true` or `false`, then compare it to one of those values. If you want to get an optional value back, use [`object(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1410095-object) (which returns an optional) instead.

Answer (score -2):

i solved like this:

```
if(Userdefaults.standart.bool(forkey: "blablabool"){

}
```

This works..
When you call this if its null it returns false.

Comment: There would be no need to check for Nil there because the output is always either true of false. It's false even for the empty value.

Comment: You'r right....